# JQuery addition from .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable count set to zero.

```
var count = 0;
```

Then I run through a .each() loop to update the count. The .text() parameter will always return a text number.

```
$(this).find('.outersubtopic').each(function(idx)
{
    var temp = $(this).text();

    count += temp;                          
});

alert(count);
```

When I hit the alert, it always reads 0008 instead of just 8.

How do I turn the .text() into a real number?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).find('.outersubtopic').each(function(idx)
{
    var temp = $(this).text();

    count += window.parseInt(temp);                          
});

alert(count);
```

window.parseInt() should do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

you have to convert it to an Number

```
$(this).find('.outersubtopic').each(function(idx)
{
    var temp = $(this).text();

     count += Number(temp);                          
});

alert(count);
```

Comment: if you use `parseInt()` you should always add the radix `parseInt(count, 10)`, if not it may convert it to a undesired value, ex: `parseInt('015') === 13` you can also use the '+' unary operator to get the integer value; `count += +temp`

Answer (score 1):

try using `parseInt`

```
  $(this).find('.outersubtopic').each(function(idx)
    {
        var temp = $(this).text();

        count += temp;                          
    });

    alert(parseInt(count));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 count += 1 * temp; // quick way to change string to number
```